# mdadm reports 2 RAID5 drives as removed, but drives have not failed

Tags: raid, mdadm

One day, I ssh to my backup server and can't connect.  So I walk over to it (yes, actually walk) and go to the console where it's telling me

```
EXT3-fs error (device dm-0): ext3_get_inode_loc: unable to read inode block - inode=62161023, block=148643591
```

And various permutations of those inodes and block numbers.  Upon a restart the software RAID (RAID 5) won't mount, and I'm seeing that 2 drives have been removed from the array but mdadm is not reporting that the drives have failed.  Curiously, the drive 1 is one that's been removed from the array and is partitioned four ways and has the boot, swap, OS, and RAID partitions on it is functioning OK, and I can boot into single user mode and poke around.  Not sure where to go from here, but it seems like the drives have not failed, but something is screwy with the RAID array or there's corruption.

I have tried to re-add the drives using mdadm but it's not working.

Any insights would be much appreciated and bring good karma.

Comment: Have you tried `mdadm --assemble --scan`?

Comment: Please post the output of `mdadm -E /dev/<disk>` and `mdadm -D /dev/<mdarray>`

Comment: mdadm --assemble --scan  results in /dev/md0 device is already in use

Comment: Here are screenshots of the output:
http://imgur.com/a/n1kgK

Comment: Please show `cat /proc/mdstat`

Comment: Results of cat /proc/mdstat

https://goo.gl/photos/2fijWZ8sygtz2FMNA

Thanks for your assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a systemctl service to assemble the mdadm array during boot.

Comment: And would you like it to get this answer without details from someone else?